# How the application does to manage the repeated signal of beacons?

Tags: beacon

I'm new in beacons and I don't understand how the application manages the signals of the beacons. Because the app can receive in a short period of time many signals from the beacon. How the application does to manage that repeated signal? If for example a beacon sends a message and half a second latter the same beacon sends another message then the application get two signals of the same beacon. It means that each time the beacon sends a message the app shows a an add to the user? or how the application knows that this message was already displayed by the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Beacons do not send messages to users.**  They only transmit a unique numeric identifier over and over again, at a typical rate of 1-10 times per second.  That's it! That is all they do!

**Most of the functionality people associate with beacons is really provided by software that runs on a mobile phone, or even running on cloud servers.**  An iOS framework or an Android library detects the beacon transmissions and converts them to one of two basic event notifications for mobile apps to process:

1. Beacon appeared/disappeared (called monitoring)
2. Beacon is still in range at an estimated distance (called ranging).

By using monitoring events, mobile apps are told when beacons first appear, and can then convert the beacon's unique identifier into a message to be displayed to the user via a lookup table bundled with the app or on a cloud server.  **Thanks to the monitoring event notifications, the message only displays once for each time the beacon is first detected by the phone.**  It will be displayed again only once the beacon goes out of range and comes back in range again.